# Styling a focused input in safari

Tags: css, safari, sass

I'm trying to apply custom styles to an input[type=range] and having issues applying those styles in Safari. Chrome, FF and IE are working properly (although FF and IE are not listed below in the code snippet).  pe-color() are external scss functions calling stored variable colors.

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 12%;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: $slider-track-height;
  background: pe-color(hyperdrive);
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid pe-color(hairline-gray);
  height: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  width: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: pe-color(white);
  margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 1px solid pe-color(basic-blue);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px pe-color(basic-blue);
}
input[type=range]::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  height: $slider-track-height;
  background: pe-color(hyperdrive);
  border: none;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid pe-color(hairline-gray);
  height: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  width: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: pe-color(white);
}
input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: 1px solid pe-color(basic-blue);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px pe-color(basic-blue);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  height: $slider-track-height;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 11px 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid pe-color(hairline-gray);
  height: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  width: $slider-thumb-diameter;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: pe-color(white);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: pe-color(hyperdrive);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: pe-color(hyperdrive);
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-thumb {
  border: 1px solid pe-color(basic-blue);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px pe-color(basic-blue);
}
```

Through various googling I have seen things referring to styling the 'outline' but I am not having success in using that.  Hoping to gain some insight if a pseudo-class style exists to target this element.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're looking for is in here https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

The reason you're not seeing any changes is because you probably haven't overwritten the default browser styling and haven't removed all outlines and images for the slider.

Check out this codepen and feel free to play around with it http://codepen.io/vveleva/pen/gwBbGB

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides browser default slider */
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  /* changes slider on click and drag */
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
  background: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}



input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: blue;
  border: 0.2px solid red;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: My apologies, I should have shown the entire file.  I have updated to reflect that.  That does not work for Safari, though.  I did come across a bug report that was opened 8 years ago for this issue and was still not resolved as of 3 years ago from webkit https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22261